# Wiremock matching path params

Tags: wiremock, url-pattern

API Specs:

GET /customer/{{customerId}}

My Target responses:

1. Input: "/customer/1234, Output: return 404 error
2. Input: "/customer/(any value not equal to 1234):  Output: 200 with return object

How do I set that any customerId path param not equal or equal to "1234" will have different outcomes?

Seems such a common scenario but I tried looking in this reference link below but can't find any

https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up two separate mappings with [different priorities](https://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/#stub-priority), so that WireMock will check for the more specific ID first.

Here's an example where the more specific url has Priority 1, and the less specific url has Priority 2, meaning WireMock checks the more specific url first, and if it does not match, checks the less specific url.

```js
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "priority": 1,
      "request": {
        "url": "/customer/1234"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 404
      }
    },
    {
      "priority": 2,
      "request": {
        "urlPath": "/customer/.*"
      },
        "response": {
            "status": 200,
            "bodyFileName": "customer.json"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked. reason why it wasnt initially working is I was using urlPattern
 for /customer/1234 when it would be just url

Comment: You could combine these approaches by using urlPathTemplate in the 2nd stub e.g. "urlPathTemplate": "/customer/{customerId}"

Comment: @Tom is `urlPathTemplate` a 3.0.0+ feature?

Comment: Yes, added in one of the recent betas:
https://wiremock.org/3.x/docs/request-matching/#path-templates

Comment: Solid :D I wasn't familiar with it and couldn't find it searching in the (not 3.x) docs.